# Bootstrap collapse and ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have issue with `ui-router` and using bootstrap collapse.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="accordion" >
    <div role="tab" id="headingOne">
       <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Click me
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            Data
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the page `localhost/#/root/mypage/`. So the 'Click me' is pointed to `localhost:\#collapseOne` that leads me to default page of my site.

Comment: that is happening because of `href="#collapseOne"` which is changing you url in browser and default page gets shown

Comment: That is clear. How to resolve  this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could simply fix you issue by using `data-target` attribute(will do the same work) instead of using `href` attribute which is affecting routing

**Markup**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="accordion" >
    <div role="tab" id="headingOne">
       <a role="button" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
          data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Click me
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel"
     aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        Data
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pankajt Glad to know that it helped others too. Thanks :-)