# Angularjs how to use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") and bootstrap Dynamic Tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using  **$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")**  to show a page by default on my site, but when i use that line of code i can't use [bootstrap  dynamic tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h), if i click on it the page sends me back to default home page.

when i click on a tab i go back to the default webpage on my site. if i comment **$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")** , the tabs work fine,
 what i can do to avoid this conflict between angularjs and the bootstrap tabs?

Comment: what do you mean by you can't use? you have nothing? an error ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis no, no error, i mean when i click on the tabs i get back to the default home page

Comment: you need to use `data-target` instead of `href`, you could go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30968066/2435473)

Comment: There is angular-strap http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap you should use with angular.

Comment: @PankajParkar ok that's should be an answer, thank you